# How to store and organize swagger files?

Tags: mongodb, swagger, storage, openapi, full-text-indexing

Suppose I need to store and organize API documentation for ~1000 REST APIs. Each API provides a [swagger](https://swagger.io/specification/) file in JSON format and text files with images for guides, tutorials, and code examples. Users may update the documentation, browse and query it by API names, URLs, request fields, etc., and also search the text files.

I can probably store the text files and images in some cloud storage (e.g. S3) and create a full-text search index. I wonder how to store the [swagger](https://swagger.io/specification/) files. Should I store them just as the text files in a cloud storage or store them in a document database (e.g. Mongo) ?

What do you think ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what do you mean by "swagger files" exactly? the generated output from openAPI schema files?

I'm wondering why would you want to host that in a database? wouldn't be so much easier to have an S3 bucket per "REST API" and make that bucket a [static web server](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html) instead? making it automatically accessible and never dependent on a connection to a secondary service?

you might still want to use the DB to organize user/editors/admins, but ultimately I would simply host everything in a CDN and make sure to override when a new update is generated and clear the cache (CloudFront), you can even have "folders" to host a version in that bucket so user could easily revert back to a previous version if any mistake...

won't you agree?

Comment: My "swagger files" are Open API definitions in JSON.

Comment: I think that a database might be better for search. What if I need to for an API with title "xyz" or all APIs with the base URL "abc*" ? Would S3 buckets be good for that ?

Comment: you can [query S3 using Amazon SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/querying-data-without-servers-or-databases-using-amazon-s3-select/), with just normal [SQL queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference.html)

Comment: Very nice but the SQL queries seem to work only for CSV files ... Would you recommend convert the JSON files to CSV ?

Comment: the idea is not to depend on any other services, CDN's these days are the best to serve static files, like an openAPI documentation `index.html` - I normally generate my docs with `redoc-cli`, it's a way to rest assure nothing will go wrong, and to update the files, delete cache and expose something to be easier fetched as query, a simple Lambda would suffice making the whole system extremely fast and cheap... but it's only how I would approach your problem, I'm sure there are more ways 

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I think I know now what to ask :))