# How to index JSON files stored in S3 by keys?

Tags: json, amazon-s3, search, indexing

Suppose I want to store hundreds of JSON files in S3. All these JSON files have the same schema. I would like to search these JSON files by keys and values: e.g. find all JSON files with a key `a` value = "abc*" and a key `x` value = "xyz" . I expect the search to return the file names and the keys that match the query.

What is the best way to index JSON files stored in S3 by keys ?

This is a follow-up of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66844273/how-to-store-and-organize-swagger-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider using `S3 Select`.

> With Amazon S3 Select, you can use simple structured query language
> (SQL) statements to filter the contents of Amazon S3 objects and
> retrieve just the subset of data that you need. By using Amazon S3
> Select to filter this data, you can reduce the amount of data that
> Amazon S3 transfers, which reduces the cost and latency to retrieve
> this data.
>
> Amazon S3 Select works on objects stored in CSV, JSON, or Apache
> Parquet format.

[Full docs on S3 Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/selecting-content-from-objects.html).

Here's a nice blog post on how to use `S3 Select`.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/querying-data-without-servers-or-databases-using-amazon-s3-select/

And a sample code would look like this:

```
import boto3

# S3 bucket to query (Change this to your bucket)
S3_BUCKET = 'greg-college-data'

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

r = s3.select_object_content(
        Bucket=S3_BUCKET,
        Key='COLLEGE_DATA_2015.csv',
        ExpressionType='SQL',
        Expression="select \"INSTNM\" from s3object s where s.\"STABBR\" in ['OR', 'IA']",
        InputSerialization={'CSV': {"FileHeaderInfo": "Use"}},
        OutputSerialization={'CSV': {}},
)

for event in r['Payload']:
    if 'Records' in event:
        records = event['Records']['Payload'].decode('utf-8')
        print(records)
```

[Code soruce](https://github.com/gregwhitaker/s3-select-example/blob/master/s3-select-example/find_colleges_by_state.py).

Comment: Thanks. I thought `S3 Select` supports only CSV. Now I wonder if they have a Java API ...

Comment: @Michael sure they do - https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/